# Vertical separation in package exercisebank and compilation

Tags: compiling, exercisebank

The vertical space that is created by the package is very big. I need to minimize it as much as possible. I need your help again.

I also have the following problem: After the change of the exercise file, the document is not compiled. What do I do afterwards? I change the size of the text in the documentclass (e.g. from 10pt to 11pt) and the document is compiled correctly. This problem started after the third exercise file added in the command: "\makeset{Set001}{ask40, ask41, ask42, **ask43, ask44, ask46, ask48, ask49, ask50, ask51**}"

My exercise file has the following structure:

```
\begin{intro}
  \begin{mdframed}
    \begin{center}
      50 - Απόδειξη της συνέχειας με υπόθεση συναρτησιακή σχέση
    \end{center}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{intro}
\begin{problem}
  Για τη συνάρτηση $ f $ ισχύει: \[ f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \] για κάθε $ x,y\in \mathbb{R} $. Να αποδειχτεί ότι:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Αν η $ f $ είναι συνεχής στο $ 0 $ θα είναι συνεχής στο $ \mathbb{R} $.
    \item Αν η $ f $ είναι συνεχής στο $ α\neq 0 $ θα είναι συνεχής στο $ \mathbb{R} $.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
  Για τη συνάρτηση $ f $ και για κάθε $ x,y>0 $ ισχύει η ισότητα \[ f(xy)=f(x)+f(y). \] Να δειχτεί ότι αν είναι συνεχής στο $ x=1 $ θα είναι συνεχής στο $ \mathbb{R}^*_+  $.
\end{problem}
```

My main file is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[total={18cm, 25.7cm}, left={1.5cm}, top={2cm}]{geometry}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{Γεώργιος Χ. Δομουχτσής} \rhead{ΣΥΝΕΧΕΙΑ ΣΥΝΑΡΤΗΣΕΩΝ}
 \lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

%\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{XITS Math}

\usepackage{mdframed}

 \usepackage{exercisebank}

\setlength{\pMarginLeft}{0pt}  % reset left margin to 0pt
\setlength{\ppMargin}{0pt}

\makeatletter                  % trim spaces around `Solution`
\gdef\@tr#1{\@ifundefined{@tr@#1}{#1}{\csname @tr@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}          % define itemize settings
%\setlist[itemize]{align=left,leftmargin=6em,labelwidth=5em,labelsep=1em}
\setlist[itemize]{align=left,leftmargin=1cm,labelwidth=1cm,labelsep=0cm}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, leftmargin=0.5cm, labelwidth=0.5cm, labelsep=0cm}

\exercisebanksetup{exercise directory=/home/geodom61/0XeLaTeX16GB/PD_SYNEXEIA/, figure root directory=/home/geodom61/0XeLaTeX16GB/PD_SYNEXEIA/FIG/}

\makeset{Set001}{ask40, ask41, ask42, ask43, ask44, ask46, ask48, ask49, ask50, ask51}

 \translateExBank{Problem=Άσκηση, Solution=Λύση}
%
% %\DisplaySolutions

\title{\textbf{Ασκήσεις στη ΣΥΝΕΧΕΙΑ ΣΥΝΑΡΤΗΣΕΩΝ}}
\author{Γεώργιος Χ. Δομουχτσής  \thanks{Οι σημειώσεις αυτές είναι ουσιαστικά η δουλειά του Δημητρίου Α. Παπακωνσταντίνου, Σχολικού Συμβούλου Μαθηματικών}}

\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\buildset{Set001}
\end{document}
```

Finally, I send you the 2nd page of my document:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [exercisebank](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) package is in its (late) alpha stage. This answer applies to version [0.1.4 (2018-04-28)](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank/tree/CTAN--0.1.4).

---

> The vertical space that is created by the package is very big. I need to minimize it as much as possible.

[`Exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) has very many vertical spaces, and I'm not really sure which one you want to remove.

Firstly, the package makes sure, by default, that all text accompanying a part problem stays on one page and similarly for solutions. This does create quite a bit unnecessary vertical space.

To disable this behaviour, you can do

```
\exercisebanksetup{tighten paragraphs=Off}
```

If you want to further decrease the vertical space you can look at the default lengths in exercisebank. However, these are not documented (yet, but will be in next version). The lengths that are affecting vertical space, with their default values, are:

```
\setlength{\pMarginBelow}{1em}  % Space below a problem ("file")
\setlength{\pMarginAbove}{1em}  % Space above a problem ("file")
\setlength{\ppMarginBelow}{2em} % Space below a part problem (the problem-environment)
\setlength{\ppMarginAbove}{2em} % Space above a part problem (the problem-environment)
```

You could set all of these to `0em` and that will remove more vertical space.

> After the change of the exercise file, the document is not compiled.

You should provide the error messages! What did you change?

> I change the size of the text in the documentclass (e.g. from 10pt to 11pt) and the document is compiled correctly.

There is nothing I can think of in the source of [`exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) that should have any influence on font size. Most likely, this error is due to something inside the `ask43`-file or perhaps `ask42`-file.

However, it *might* be caused by having very big `problem`-environments in combination with the paragraph tightening feature. If this is the case, it should be solved by using the above `tighten paragraphs=Off`.

---

On a different note

I haven't really tested the package with the `twocolumn`, and this might be a source to many weird behaviours. If you just want to show all exercises you can do `\sprite` instead of `\buildset`.

Also, there is one command, `\squeeze`, that will really squeeze everything down, but I suspect it might be a bit much.

Comment: Simple changes in exercise files (or adding a new exercise file in \buildset command) and compilation presents the previous pdf file without error messages. If I delete the pdf file (or change the letter size), compilation produces the correct pdf.

Comment: Doesn't really help. I strongly suspect that error is in one of the files, and not in `exercisebank`.

Comment: The vertical space between part problems changes when I change the \pMarginAbove and not the \ppMarginAbove!

Comment: Try downloading [this prerelease](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank/blob/edge/exercisebank.zip) and see if it helps? (Just put the `exercisebank.sty` into your project working directory)

Comment: I installed the prerelease and the vertical spacing is OK. The problem is that the labels of the part problems are outside(in front of) the text column. How can I correct the command "\setlist[itemize]{align=left,leftmargin=2cm,labelwidth=1cm,labelsep=1cm}" in order to solve this problem. I shall continue to use the prerelease.

Comment: @GeorgeDomus Remove the `\setlist`-command and do `\exercisebanksetup{style margins=Off}`. Also remember to check for updates. I'll keep the link in the previous comment up to date until `0.2.0` is released :)

Comment: Where can I find the definitions of all of the "\margins"?

Comment: In the docs in the zip-file. The margins are defined [here](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank/blob/edge/src/problemstyle.tex)

Comment: Excellent! The horizontal spacing works fine with "style margins=Off" and the vertical spacing (between part problems) works fine with "\setlength{\pMarginBelow}{1em}". Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the impression (after a lot of experimentation) that there is some mistake in the definitions of the \pMargin* and the \ppMargin*. My experiments showed that (in the previous edition as well) \ppMargin* do not work. \pMarginBelow works both for the title of the exercise and the part problem and the \pMarginAbove works only for the title of the exercise.

Comment: @GeorgeDomus I will look into it. But please report stuff like this [at the bug tracker here](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank/issues)